# Cannot Assign Param Value in Model Collection. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection, model, custom-table

I'm currently Facing a really strange Issue I'm applying filter on my custom table data in grid by adding function

> Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Withdrawal/Grid/Collection.php

```
protected function _renderFiltersBefore() {
        $id = (int)$this->request->getParam('id');
        // echo $id;
        // print_r($id);exit;
        $this->getSelect()->where('main_table.seller_id ='. $id);
        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
    }
```

Now the filter is working Fine when I apply the value Hard coded... like `$this->getSelect()->where('main_table.seller_id = 2');` it works fine even if I assign *variable* a hard coded value like `$id=2` then it also works fine... but when I get the value by **Param** then it do not return any data while as you can see in my code that I've *echo* the **ID** n it is returning the proper value but when I assign it to Query then it is not working... what is the issue n how to sort this thanks.

Comment: I think it's something to do with the data types of both, seller_id and the $id you get through request->param().

Comment: at first I was thinking the same but then I compare these with `===` in if condition thats why I've assigned the int in my Param coz at int they were same